# XSLT: Passing Parameters for record filtering to XSL:IF expression

Tags: xslt

I have an XML given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Mucik Master</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>Will Smith</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
    <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Soulsville</title>
    <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
    <country>Norway</country>
    <company>WEA</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The very best of</title>
    <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Island</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Stop</title>
    <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>A and M</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
    <artist>T`Pau</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Siren</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Private Dancer</title>
    <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Capitol</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Midt om natten</title>
    <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Medley</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
    <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>DECCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1991</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The dock of the bay</title>
    <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Elektra</company>
    <price>7.20</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSL file for Filtering records given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:if test = "country = 'USA'">
     <cd>
    <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
    </cd>
    </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transformed output XML file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd><title>Empire Burlesque</title></cd>
<cd><title>Greatest Hits</title></cd>
<cd><title>When a man loves a woman</title></cd>
<cd><title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title></cd>
<cd><title>Big Willie style</title></cd>
<cd><title>The dock of the bay</title></cd>
<cd><title>Unchain my heart</title></cd>
</catalog>
```

Here filtering condition has been hardcoded in XLST as country='USA'

But I need to pass the filtering value ie; USA as Parameter to XSLT while executing. something like country='$USA'

How to pass this country value as parameter to XSL file

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<xsl:param name="country"/>
```

above your `<xsl:template>` and replace the if by

```
<xsl:if test="country = $country">
```

The way to pass the parameter will vary according to xsl processor used.
E.g.

`xsltproc --stringparam country USA your.xsl you.xml`

Answer (score -2):

Write

```
<xsl:param name="country"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[country=$country]">
     <cd>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
     </cd>
    </xsl:for-each>
</catalog>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm a little bit surprised you should need to come to StackOverflow with such a basic question. Personally, before I start coding in any new language, I get myself a book on the topic and skim-read it from cover to cover. It saves a lot of time.